# Create a Kubernetes Service that loads an external host url AND port

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I have a url like this:  `http://myserver.mydomain.com:98765`

I need to have this url be a Kubernetes service so I can address it in Kubernetes like this: `my-service.mynamespace.svc.cluster.local`.  (So, if I run `curl http://my-service.mynamespace.svc.cluster.local/metrics` from inside my cluster, it will return the same value as calling `curl https://myserver.mydomain.com:98765/metrics`.)

I have tried to make a `Service` of type `ExternalName`.  But external name cannot support ports.  So instead, I have to run: `curl http://my-service.mynamespace.svc.cluster.local:98765/metrics`  (that does not work for what I am doing).

I also looked into using a "headless service" with a Kubernetes `Endpoint`.  This looks like it will allow me to specify a port, but an `Endpoint` only supports using IP addresses.  My company frowns on hardcoding IP addresses.  So that solution is not very good either.

**Is there a way to use a host name AND use a port when making a Kubernetes service that accesses an external URL?**

In case anyone wants know what this for, I have a Rabbit MQ server (external to Kubernetes) that exposes prometheus metrics.  I need to wrap that in a Kubernetes service so that my Prometheus operator can find the service with a label on it and pull the metrics in.

Comment: see attached link, this is what you need? an endpoint https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69368058/how-can-i-proxy-an-external-site-through-my-kubernetesopenshift-ingress/69368157#69368157

Comment: @SiddiqueAhmad - Thank you for looking into my issue.  Unfortunately, that uses `Endpoints`, which only supports IP addresses.